# Restrict customer edit access for different admins in magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, customer, user-roles, acl, module-development

I have magento2 with different admins. I don't want my admins to edit any customer details. They should only view. My different admin can place an order by clicking on "Login as Customer" Button. So they can only add "new shipping/billing" address. but they should not be able to update any already stored information of customer from admin panel or frontend.

How can I do that in Magento 2.4.6? thanks

Comment: Customization is required in this request.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Magento 2 Admin Panel.

Navigate to Role Resources:
Go to System > Permissions > User Roles.

Select Admin Role:
Choose the admin role that you want to restrict.

Edit Role Resources:
In the "Role Resources" section, expand the "Customers" tab.

Adjust Customer Permissions:
Disable the "Save" and "Edit" permissions for customer information.

**Just remember to make sure this is a new role not the primary role for admin**

Comment: There is no option to disable edit button. In roles section there is only option to restrict delete access